# Why does my camera no longer display in the Photoshop Elements dropdown?

Tags: troubleshooting, file-transfer, photoshop-elements

When I plug my camera into my PC using the USB cable, and open Photoshop Elements, I no longer see my camera in the drop-down list when trying to acquire/download images. The camera is on, the battery is good, etc. (I've done this "a million" times in the past).

What is the most likely problem? I'm thinking the cable has given up the proverbial ghost, but I don't want to spring for another cable if there's something else I can try first.

It's a Canon "Digital Rebel", about five years old.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a better fit for http://superuser.com

Comment: Can you see the camera in "My Computer"?, have you tried a different cable?

Comment: As mentioned, I am holding off buying a new cable, because I don't want to do that if it's not necessary. Where would I look in "My Computer" to find the camera? Should it populate an "installed hardware" section or some such?